# Update Duplicated Items In list View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to add an items to a list view (Win form application), if the user add an item more than one time the list view should only update the item and add 1 to quantity
i am trying to update the list view but i get an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
```

first i am trying to find if the item exist in the list view 
and then update the item in list view

```
string ScanedItem = "A"
ListViewItem ITM = listView1.FindItemWithText(ScanedItem);
if (ITM != null)
{
   int i = ITM.Index;
   listView1.SelectedItems[i].SubItems[0].Text = "2";
}
else
{
 var LastAddedItem = BasketItems.Last();
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(LastAddedItem.Item_Name);
 lvi.SubItems.Add("£ " + LastAddedItem.Item_Price.ToString());
 lvi.SubItems.Add(LastAddedItem.Item_Quantity.ToString());
 lvi.SubItems.Add("£ " + LastAddedItem.Total_Item.ToString());
 listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

any help or advice would be great

Comment: At what line does the exception occur? I have the feeling `.SubItem[0]` doesn't have any elements or can't be accessed with integers as indexes.

Comment: I don't get it - what do you mean by "more than one time the list view should only update the item"  - you need to specify what you are trying to do.  Pls remove redundant code and comment your code and where is the variable `BasketItems`defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listView1.SelectedItems` are for items that are selected in the list view. There no items selected in your case.

You need to use `listView1.Items` instead. This is a collection of all items in your listview